# I have written a function in PHP that calls show-form(); how to call it inside jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is in an [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) file. In the `else` section, I want to call a `show-form();` function which is in an `example.php` page. Also, what's the complete syntax for `$.post();`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function nis(id){
        $(id).show("slow").delay(4000).hide("slow");
    }

    $(function() {
        setAutoComplete("searchField", "results", "autocomplete.php?part=");

        $('form[name=frm]').submit(function(event) {
            if($("#searchField").val().length===0)
            {
                nis('.divmsg');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $.post("example.php", function() {});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is in `example.php` .. which is for giving you a declaration for any word you write in searchField.

```
<?php
    function show_form()
    {
        echo'<div  class="divmsg"> Wronge input :: </div>';
        echo'  <form name="frm" method="post" action="index.php?act=sm"> ';
        echo'<p class="textplz">Tybe a Definition you want ?!';
        echo'<p id="auto" >';
        echo'Word : <input id="searchField" type="text" name="searchField" />    <input  id="for-submitbutton" type="submit" name="sbm" value="Definition" /> ';
        echo' </p> </p>  </form>';
    }

    function submited()
    {
        require("dbconn.inc");
        $word=$_POST['searchField'];
        $sql="select * from definition where word like '".$word."'";

        $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
        if(@mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
        {
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
             $vie=$rows["declation"];
            }
            echo('
                <br />
                <br />
                <form name="frm" method="post" action="index.php?act=sm"> <p id="auto" >
                    Word : <input id="searchField" type="text" name="searchField" /> <input id="for-submitbutton" type="submit" name="sbm" value="Definition" />
                </p> </form> ');
            echo('<div class="answer">');
            print $word ;
            echo('<br><p id="dev">');
            print $vie;
            echo ("</h4><br></p></div>");
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using `$.post`, not sending data and the expecting the `$_GET` value to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The complete syntax for `$.post()` is:

   ```
   $.post(url, data, callback, type);
   ```
2. In your case:

   ```
   $.post("example.php", null,  function() {});
   ```

If you want to send some parameters, use `{param1: "123", param2: "123}` instead of `null`.

Comment: ok ..put how can i get the param inside php ?? 
can i use ?? 
$.post("example.php", {param1 : ("#searchField").val()},function() {
            alert(data)});

and in example.php :submited($_POST['searchField']); //to call the function which is in above ??

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a dash is not valid in PHP identifiers. Your function is called "show_form", please refer to it as such in the rest of your text.

Secondly, PHP scripts run on the server, whereas Javascript (and jQuery) run on the client. Your client only receives a HTML document, meaning that the PHP code has already been processed and executed.

So, you cannot possibly call a PHP code from jQuery as if it were a Javascript function.

What you can do:

- Invoke a PHP script on the server using a POST or GET request. You can find the parameter list for these in the jQuery online documentation
- Emit Javascript code in your HTML, possibly generated using PHP code, so that you can call that later on your client

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this:

```
$.post("example.php", { "act": "form" } );
```

But also you should use $_POST variable inside of PHP-script.

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX call, you need to process the result like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'example.php',
...
success: function(data){
// process data
  }
})
```

Comment: in a process data section can i write a    :  show-form(); ??

Comment: The php file needs to return some xml or string or html that $.ajax can process in success: function(data). You cannot call a specific function, in any way.

Comment: On second thought, you can try passing a POST variable to the url, and then process it in you php file with $_POST